# Recreated dynamically updating daily page view count

Tags: html, flexbox, shopify, e-commerce

I am styling the product page of my site using the following example page: https://hismileteeth.com/products/colour-corrector

They have this awesome little view count that shows the an updating count of the current page visitors.

Now unfortunately I don't have a $B+ brand with hundreds of people on my product page every second to show off, but I was thinking that maybe instead I could display the same kind of updating count for total daily page views in the last 24hrs.

I tried inspecting the page element, but wasn't able to make too much of it. If anyone knows how I could achieve this, that would be awesome!

I'm doing this inside of Shopify in case that's relevant.

Thank you so much any advance for any assistance :)

I tried inspecting the page, and saw a flex element, but I'm not sure how to build this out.